# How to use search from python-ldap

Tags: python-3.x, search, radix, python-ldap

I need to execute following command in python:

```
ldapsearch -H ldap://10.120.80.17:300 -x -LLL "uid=cich"
```

then I get this as output in bash:

```
dn: employeeNumber=621,ou=Internal,ou=People,o=NSN
mail: name.surname@example.com
objectClass: nsnEDPerson
objectClass: inetorgperson
objectClass: organizationalPerson
objectClass: person
objectClass: top
objectClass: dspswuser
objectClass: posixAccount
objectClass: shadowAccount
nsnSiteCode: 600906
gidNumber: 555
uid: cich
loginShell: /bin/bash
homeDirectory: /home/cich
nsnPrimaryEmailAddress: name.surname@example.com
gecos: surname name
employeeNumber: 6216
cn: surname name
uidNumber: 6216
```

this is what I tried to execute in python by using python-ldap lib, but it doesn't work, im getting error in last line with 'result'

```
import ldap

con = ldap.initialize('ldap://10.120.80.17:300')
ldap_base = "ou=Internal,ou=People,o=NSN"
query = "(uid=cich)"
result = con.search_s(ldap_base, ldap.SCOPE_SUBTREE, query)
```

I think I don't understand what I have to put in ldap_base, could you explain?

there is some documentation from lib:

```
  def search_ext(self,base,scope,filterstr=None,attrlist=None,attrsonly=0,serverctrls=None,clientctrls=None,timeout=-1,sizelimit=0):
    """
    search(base, scope [,filterstr='(objectClass=*)' [,attrlist=None [,attrsonly=0]]]) -> int
    search_s(base, scope [,filterstr='(objectClass=*)' [,attrlist=None [,attrsonly=0]]])
    search_st(base, scope [,filterstr='(objectClass=*)' [,attrlist=None [,attrsonly=0 [,timeout=-1]]]])
    search_ext(base,scope,[,filterstr='(objectClass=*)' [,attrlist=None [,attrsonly=0 [,serverctrls=None [,clientctrls=None [,timeout=-1 [,sizelimit=0]]]]]]])
    search_ext_s(base,scope,[,filterstr='(objectClass=*)' [,attrlist=None [,attrsonly=0 [,serverctrls=None [,clientctrls=None [,timeout=-1 [,sizelimit=0]]]]]]])

        Perform an LDAP search operation, with base as the DN of
        the entry at which to start the search, scope being one of
        SCOPE_BASE (to search the object itself), SCOPE_ONELEVEL
        (to search the object's immediate children), or SCOPE_SUBTREE
        (to search the object and all its descendants).

        filter is a string representation of the filter to
        apply in the search (see RFC 4515).

        Each result tuple is of the form (dn,entry), where dn is a
        string containing the DN (distinguished name) of the entry, and
        entry is a dictionary containing the attributes.
        Attributes types are used as string dictionary keys and attribute
        values are stored in a list as dictionary value.

        The DN in dn is extracted using the underlying ldap_get_dn(),
        which may raise an exception of the DN is malformed.

        If attrsonly is non-zero, the values of attrs will be
        meaningless (they are not transmitted in the result).

        The retrieved attributes can be limited with the attrlist
        parameter.  If attrlist is None, all the attributes of each
        entry are returned.

        serverctrls=None

        clientctrls=None

        The synchronous form with timeout, search_st() or search_ext_s(),
        will block for at most timeout seconds (or indefinitely if
        timeout is negative). A TIMEOUT exception is raised if no result is
        received within the time.

        The amount of search results retrieved can be limited with the
        sizelimit parameter if non-zero.
    """
```

Comment: It's not really clear whether you actually have a problem with your Python script or you only need general understanding.

Answer (score 0):

Argument `base` is the search base or sometimes called search root. It specifies the sub-tree of the whole directory information tree (DIT) where you start searching. It has the same meaning like command-line option `-b` of the *ldapsearch* tool. Your local configuration (file [ldap.conf](https://www.openldap.org/software/man.cgi?query=ldap.conf)) probably contains a default value for this.

Most times you choose the top-level entry of the database of your LDAP server for this. If your LDAP server grants read access to the root DSE you can query the "naming contexts" of the various databases on your LDAP server like this:

```
ldapsearch -H ldap://10.120.80.17:300 -x -LLL -b "" namingContexts
```